# Github readme latest version of a project release

Tags: github, markdown, release, readme, github-release

```sh
$ yarn add https://github.com/nameUser/nameProject/releases/download/vA.B.C-alpha/file-A.B.C.tgz
```

I have a similar thing in the readme of my project, I would like to make sure that every time a version is released it does not have to update this part which is in the readme.

So I was thinking of developing a service that, given a `username` and a `project`, returns the url of the latest release that can be downloaded.

The problem how can I make the text possible to be copied as seen in the image.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can make the text copyable?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a copy button to your README?